# Finding the integers roots of 2 variables polynomial $x^2-xy+y^2-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm looking for a way to convince myself that the roots of the polynomial  $x^2-xy+y^2-1$ s.t $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ are bounded with $|x|,|y|\leq 1$.
Is there is a way to present the sets of roots as elipse?

Comment: Well, the set of roots in $\mathbb R$ **is** obviously an ellipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As
$$x^2-xy+y^2-1=\frac{(x-y)^2+x^2+y^2}2-1 $$
any root will have
$$ (x-y)^2+x^2+y^2=2$$
and for integers this means that one of the three squares is $0$ and the other two are $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x,y)=x^2-xy+y^2-1$. Then $\nabla f(x,y)=(2 x - y, 2 y - x)$. The bounding rectangle for the ellipse is found by solving these equations:

- $f(x,y)=0$, $2x-y=0$; solve for $y$
- $f(x,y)=0$, $2y-x=0$; solve for $x$

This gives a square centered at the origin: $[-L,L] \times [-L,L]$, where $L=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}<2$.

[image]